# Accessing shared keychain data from embedded command-line tool

Tags: swift, xcode, keychain

My sandboxed macOS app stores server credentials in the keychain using [KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess), and this works perfectly.

I have also written a command line tool, which is embedded into the app's bundle. I'd like this tool to also have access to the passwords stored in the Keychain by the main app.

HOWEVER, for the life of me I cannot get the two to share access to the same keychain items. The command-line tool always pops up the "auth dialog":

[image]

I suspect my code is correct. In both the main app and the tool, the following does give me access to the password data from the keychain:

```
let keychain = Keychain(service: "serviceName", accessGroup: "24F6D23HXS.com.obfuscated.app-name")
```

I am guessing my problem is in the configuration of the two projects in Xcode. For the macOS app, I have "app target > Capabilities > Keychain Sharing" turned on, and the keychain group it generated there is what's used in the code above (`24F6D23HXS.com.obfuscated.app-name`). Turning this on also caused a provisioning profile to be generated, which seems fine.

However, the target settings for the command line tool has no Capabilities section, so I can't turn on "Keychain Sharing". Also there's no apparent way to select the provisioning profile the macOS app is using (not sure if I need to do this or not).

Can anyone give me any pointers on how to get this working?

Comment: Are you selecting "always allow" when the authorization comes up?

Comment: select "always allow" instead of "allow"

Comment: I realise I could select either one of those, and it does work. However, I do not want the dialog to appear at all. Both the app and the tool should have immediate access to the keychain data that I am trying to configure them to share.